# Bitwise operator doesn't work as it supposed to in C++

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bit

I'm trying to find whether a particular string has all unique characters in it or not. My approach is like this, I'm initializing a variable of 64 bit, say ***places*** and setting it to 0.  Now, I'm iterating over the string and calculating the difference between of ASCII between current character and 'A'(smallest ASCII possible). If (places & (1"<<"pos)) is already set, the string does not have unique characters.

Everything works fine but with only lowercase characters. The moment I add test with uppercase, the code doesn't work anymore. I'm sure its something with my variable ***places*** but I don't know what exactly is wrong.

Here is the code for the same :

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void check_unique(string s){
    int64_t places=0;       
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){   
    int pos=s[i]-'A';            
    if((places & (1<<pos))!=0){  
        cout<<"String does not have all unique characters\n";   
        return;
    }
    places|=(1<<pos);            
  }
   cout<<"String has all unique characters\n";   
}

int main() {
    check_unique("abcde"); // Testcase 1
    check_unique("aabb");  // Testcase 2
    check_unique("ABbde");   // Testcase 3, Wrong output.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Less efficient but it looks really cool: `return std::unoreded_set{s.begin(), s.end()}.size() == s.size();`

Comment: Pop quiz: what do you get if you try `std::cout << (1 << 32) << std::endl;` The answer might surprise you. Now, compute the difference between the ascii value of lowercase and uppercase letters, and you should be able to figure it out yourself.

Comment: Well why don't you debug your code and see why it fails?

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks, but I am writing a tutorial and in that I am demonstrating different ways to do same task. I have written something very similar to what you mentioned already. Can you help me with this solution ?

Comment: Hint: Hown many bits are allowed in a `int64_t` ? Compare with `pos - 'A'`

Comment: @Quimby I did already. It is treating uppercase and lowercase same. I can't really figure out myself so came for help.

Comment: Pop quiz #2: See what happens when you try to see what you get from `std::cout << (1 << n) << std::endl;` with `n` being an `int` value. Start with `n` being, oh, say 29, and work your way up, one bit a time. There's no reason for you to ask anything else, any more. This should be sufficient for you to figure it out, by yourself. Good luck.

Comment: @Arkadiy: ASCII(A) = 65,   ASCII(a)=97. And no UB because int64_t is signed

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thanks, I will do the same.

Comment: Unrelated: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` should not be used ([why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)) and `using namespace std;` should be avoided ([why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)). Together they reinforce some of the other's worst behaviours, resulting in some very hard to understand errors. Do not do this.

Comment: @user4581301 My bad, I shouldn't use it definitely. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik My '1' is 32 bit and left shifting it with >32 might returning a garbage value. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++ constants have type, in your case 1 has type `int` and it seems your platform has 32 bit ints, so when you use lowercase letters you get out of range. Obvious solution is to use constant of type long - `1L` or even better unsigned long `1UL`. You can use cast as well:

```
static_cast<uint64_t>(1) << pos
```

Comment: Some platforms only have 32 bit longs as well, so `1UL` won't work there either.  use `UINT64_C(1)` to get a constant literal of type uint64_t..

Comment: You were great help. I realised that my 1 is a 32 bit integer and I am left-shifting it with more than 32 bit, so it might be returning a garbage value. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @LightYagmi It doesn't evaluate a garbage value - it evaluates to 0.